# <?php if( get_field('archief') == true): ?> is not wroking

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Im working in WordPress and i have a custom post type "faillissement". I have 2 page's where i want to show the custom post types. So i gave it a option (checkbox) to select so it also shows up on the other page. When the checkbox ("archief") is checked it puts out true, when its not checked it doesnt put out anything. To filter the post if made this code what i have used befor and it works.`<?php if( get_field('archief') === true): ?>`. But this time it doesnt show any custom post. I have made 4 custom post's , 2 with the checkbox checked and 2 not. When i remove the "=== true" it brings up all the post's, so it's getting the post's. What am i doing wrong? Here is the code to get the custom post's that i use.

```
                <?php
            $temp = $wp_query;
            $wp_query = null;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query();
            $wp_query->query("order=ASC&showpost=24&post_status=publish&post_type=faillissement");
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php if( get_field('archief') === true): ?>
                        <tr>
                <td>

                <a href="<?=get_the_permalink();?>" class="default"> <?php the_field('bedrijfsnaam'); ?></a>
                </td>
                <td> <?php the_field('plaats'); ?></td>
                <td> <?php the_field('curator'); ?></td>
                <td><a href="   <?=get_the_permalink();?>">Details&gt;&gt;</a>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

To conclude, I only want to show a custom post type when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Are you SURE that get_field will return a boolean true? done a `var_dump(get_field(...))` to confirm? `===` requires exact matches on value AND type.

Comment: Do you know how `if()` works? Also take a look at: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/

Comment: I have used var_dump on    <?php var_dump( get_field('archief')); ?>    to confirm, and i got 'array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } array(1) { [""]=> string(0) "" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" } array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "true" }'  and thats correct. On    <?php var_dump( get_field('archief') === true); ?>    i got 'bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)'    . that shows it does get the value.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found out that the custom post type was currupted in the functions.php, when i made a new custom post type it was fixed.